# Google Apps Script formatDate using user's time zone instead of GMT

Tags: javascript, time, google-apps-script, timezone, timezone-offset

In a function within Google Apps Script I am using [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

```
let formattedTimestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "hh:mm a");
```

The resulting string is a timestamp in the `GMT` time zone but I need it to be in the current user's time zone, and account for daylight saving time.

The documentation links to the [Java SimpleDateFormat class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but I can't find a list of valid time zones with which I'd replace `GMT`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can directly get the spreadsheet Time Zone like this :

```
  var addedDate = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var addedTime = Utilities.formatDate(addedDate, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a");
```

See [doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getSpreadsheetTimeZone%28%29)

but Google Apps Script uses these formats if you want to choose it yourself :

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

Comment: Update: `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` also worked for my needs. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session

Comment: @mike: One potential problem with using `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` is if you deploy the script across timezones. Your end-user in a different tz will end up with timestamps synced to the script's tz rather than the spreadsheet's tz.