# How to create the timestamp only on the first edit of columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a certain amount of column and a timestamp dedicated first column. My code works but updates every time and I would like it to only update on the first edit.

I have tried to add some code that I found but unsuccessfully.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    cols = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    colStamp = 1,
    ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
    if (s.getName() !== 'Feedback' || ind == -1) return;
e.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind]))
    .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);} 
{ if (e.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind])).getValue() === '') 
{ e.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind])).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);}}
```

I don't have any error message, the last part of code when active is making the whole code not working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Add timestamp to cell on first edit of that row.

---

#### Solution:

Use `onEdit(e)` simple trigger along with an `if` statement to make sure the timestamp column is blank before setting the date value.

---

#### Example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var stampCol = sh.getRange(row, 1);

  //check if "stampCol" is empty      
  if (!stampCol.getValue()) {
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss');
    stampCol.setValue(date); //set timestamp
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

I've defined `var stampCol` as column 1 for the same row that is edited. The `if` statement then checks if `stampCol` is empty, if so then it'll timestamp the row. By checking if `stampCol` is empty, it stops the script from writing timestamps to that row on every edit, because it'll only be empty the first time it runs.

Then by using `Utilities.formatDate()` I've created a timestamp with the format defined in the script, you can change this to how you'd like it to be displayed. Currently it's using the spreadsheet's timezone from `var tz`, you can also change this to use your preferred timezone setting.

Here are some time zone options in Google Apps Script:

```
//use spreadsheet timezone setting
var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

//use script timezone setting
var tz = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

//enter your own time zone
var tz = 'GMT+0';
```

---

#### References:

1. [Simple
   Triggers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
2. [Time
   Zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596933/google-apps-script-formatdate-using-users-time-zone-instead-of-gmt)
3. [Date Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response!

Thanks a lot for the answer and explanations, it seems to work pretty fine.

If I have issues I'll comment here.

Cheers!